# Node-redis very long initial connect

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Sometimes my node-redis client take a long time to a initial connect to redis server.

I log .on('error'), .on('end'), .on('connect') and .on('ready') events here:

```
Redis:  storage#0 <localhost:6381> end
Redis: error storage#0 <localhost:6381> [Error: Redis connection to localhost:6381 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND]
/*... much of same errors, sometimes up to 5minutes ...*/
Redis: error storage#0 <localhost:6381> [Error: Redis connection to localhost:6381 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND]
Redis:  storage#0 <localhost:6381> connect
Redis:  storage#0 <localhost:6381> ready
```

While it happened I can normally connect to the redis-server using redis-cli.

Have somebody any ideas about reason of this?

Comment: I have no idea about the reason, but you may want to use 127.0.0.1 to connect instead of localhost, so you avoid a call to the DNS which may fail.

Comment: :( Nothing changed: `Redis: error storage#0 <127.0.0.1:6381> [Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6381 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED]`

Comment: Well the error code is different ... Perhaps, you have defined a too aggressive connection timeout? It is one of the options at connection time (and it is expressed in millisecond).

Comment: a week passed and I not to get this error more) I believe I get ECONNREFUSED because redis-server been inaccessible. Great thanks. I don't knew earlier that localhost resolving can failed.

Comment: @DidierSpezia, Hi, I review and mark my questions, can you post your first comment as the answer? It helps me...

Comment: I've just done it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error "[Error: Redis connection to localhost:6381 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND]" seems to point to an address resolution issue.

A simple proposal was therefore to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost to bypass the call to getaddrinfo, and the associated DNS query which can fail.

The result with 127.0.0.1 was slightly different: still an error, but the message was now ECONNREFUSED meaning that the remote Redis server was probably not listening to the provided port - or perhaps the connection timeout was set too low.